# NodeJS encoding issue for non-ascii chracter like 'æ' while making REST API call

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, character-encoding

I am making a web app which communicates to Parse REST API calls. I am saving, deleting data which is all working fine for normal text but when non ASCII characters such as 'æ' or other Swedish characters appear in string I get this error

`STATUS: 400
HEADERS: {"server":"Cowboy","connection":"keep-alive","x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-methods":"GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS","access-control-allow-headers":"X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type","access-control-expose-headers":"X-Parse-Job-Status-Id, X-Parse-Push-Status-Id","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"40","date":"Sat, 14 Dec 2019 15:59:32 GMT","via":"1.1 vegur"}
BODY: {"error":"Unexpected end of JSON input"}`

The JSON data is :
`{"gymname":"Sivmosevænget","geolocation":{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":"55.3536746","longitude":"10.5432"}}`

And I have also set the encoding in options to 
`"Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

And I have also tried posting same data through Postman and it worked there. So it is not problem with Parse. Most probably encoding issue but I have tried to resolve that without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. It was an issue with content-length. I think the encoding difference was making content length different as expected by server.(Correct me if I am wrong here but there is no other logic to it.)

Removed the Content-Length from the request options and the issue got solved.

Anyways it got solved but not still sure about why this was occurring. Because what ever the encoding may be Content-Length should remain the same.